# R Programming - What is use of "="complete.obs"" in the code below

Tags: r

What is use of "="complete.obs"" in the code below?

```
corrplot(corr=cor(cust.df[ , c(2, 3, 5:12)], use="complete.obs"), method 
="ellipse")
```

[image: Visualization achieved by this code]

Comment: "If use is "all.obs", then the presence of missing observations will produce an error. If use is "complete.obs" then missing values are handled by casewise deletion (and if there are no complete cases, that gives an error). " from the help

Comment: Welcome to SO, Animesh. Have you checked the help for the `cor()` function? To do so, enter `?cor` from the R console.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no evidence of attempted research prior to posting

Comment: I'm voting to close because BenBolker said so.

Answer (score 2):

`use="complete.obs"` is using all available observations to create a correlation matrix. Without it, correlations are calculated only when no data is missing.

For example:

```
data(mtcars)
cars_mini <- mtcars[,3:6]
# remove data
cars_mini[1,1] <- NA
cars_mini[1,2] <- NA

library(corrplot)
corrplot(corr=cor(cars_mini, use="complete.obs"), method="ellipse")
```

Returns:

[image]

Whereas `corrplot(corr=cor(cars_mini), method="ellipse")` gives:

[image]